# Streamlit - How can I retrieve edited dataframe in callback

Tags: streamlit

I'm using the newly released `experimental_data_editor` instead of st-aggrid, and there are many interesting features. However, I'm confused with the usage of the callback function, as it does not let me access the changed dataframe; I only have information on changed cells or added/removed rows. My plan is to save the dataframe on a DB in a callback as soon as it is changed.

I think I could use the session state information (changed cells information) in conjunction to the `_apply_dataframe_edits` function in `streamlit.elements.data_editor` to get the edited version of the dataframe, but that sounds like heavy lifting. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

This works, but it's a bit awkward :

```python
import streamlit as st
from streamlit.elements.data_editor import _apply_dataframe_edits
from streamlit import type_util

def f():
    t = st.session_state['t']
    t = type_util.convert_anything_to_df(t)
    _apply_dataframe_edits(t, st.session_state['st_t'])
    make_use_of_edited_dataframe(t)

t: pd.DataFrame = load_my_dataframe()
st.experimental_data_editor(t, on_change=f, key='st_t')
st.session_state['t'] = t
```